# Magento mail doesn't allow special characters

Tags: magento-1.9, utf-8, special-character

Mail doesn't allow special characters. I'm using Custom Formbuilder as a module.
The email I'm receiving is turning special characters like this: Ü into Ã¼. I've already looked into topics like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094023/zend-mail-with-french-characters-in-mail-body and I have UTF-8 enabled. How do I fix this?

Comment: can you please provide your code. we will check

Comment: What code would you like to see? The form is build with Formbuilder

Comment: shall i knwo where you are enable UTF-8 ?

Comment: Well I've tried doing so through Meta tags, in index.php and with Zend_Mail